# Google-sheet: select related cell from imported range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have the following google-sheet:

```
|  |   A    |    B   |    C   |   D    |
| 1|        | Item1  | Item2  | Item3  | 
| 2| Value1 |   yes  |  no    |  no    | 
| 3| Value2 |   no   |  no    |  yes   | 
| 4| Value3 |   no   |  yes   |  no    |
```

I need to import specific data from this sheet into another range so result should contain values from A, which have "yes" between B:E, and related item from the first row, like:

```
Value1 Item1
Value2 Item3
Value3 Item2
```

I can import using query and condition for "yes", but no ideas how to read related cell with Item1, Item2.. from first row above:

```
=query({importrange("my_range_id", "Data!A1:Z999"}, "select Col1 where Col2='yes' or Col3='yes' or Col4='yes'")
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

May be you can first import data, then retrieve the column corresponding to 'yes' by this formula using matrix multiplication

```
={A2:A5,arrayformula(mmult((if(B2:D5="yes",1,0)),transpose(column(B1:D1)-1)))}
```

and then retrieve the header of the column

```
=offset($A$1,,G2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an addition, in case you still want to use a query:

Try this in F2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A2:A<>"", 
 "♦"&A2:A&""&B1:D1&""&B2:D, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), ""),"Select Col1,Col2 where Col3 contains 'YES'"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an integrated formula

```
={A2:A,arrayformula(vlookup(mmult((if($B$2:$D="yes",1,0)),transpose(column($B$1:$D$1)-1)),{arrayformula(transpose(COLUMN(A1:D1)-1)),transpose(A1:D1)},2,0))}
```